# Selenium Ruby Webdriver unable to run Chrome browser

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am attempting to start a remote session for chrome and keep getting the same issue. The script isn't that complicated.
I am wondering if it isn't some switch that might be set incorrectly. Below is a snippet of code I am using along with the error I am getting back (or part of it, very long). I see the browser attempt to open and then immediately close.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class PageLinks < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
    @caps['chrome.switches'] = %w[--ignore-certificate-errors]
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for( :remote, :url => 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', :desired_capabilities => @caps )
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 200
    @driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 200
    @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 200)
    @verification_errors = []
  end


  def teardown
    @driver.quit
  end


  def test_pagelinks
    @driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
    @driver.find_element(:link, "HOME").click
```

### ....

```
test_pagelinks(PageLinks):
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: [GET, HEAD, DELETE]
Command duration or timeout: 2 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:04'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_03'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver (org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException)
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl():-2:in `newInstance0'
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl():-1:in `newInstance'
```

.........

Answer (score 1):

The page_load timeout setting is an experimental feature in the Firefox driver, and not supported by the Chrome driver yet.

Comment: Oh man thanx! that was really making my head hurt.. I took that one line out and everything is kicking off like a charm.  I may ask this as a separate question, but I was wondering if you knew of anything similar to that with IE.  Also, is there some grand document that has these secrets, or do I just need to run through the various changelogs and readmes until I get more comfortable with this?    Sorry for the somewhat dim follow ups but we're just starting to try selenium out at my office and we don't really have any experts to just go ask. Thanks again!